# jQuery - click event not working firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

The following code works correctly in Chrome & Safari but won't work in Firefox.

```
$(".contact-link").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".project").remove();
    $("#main").removeClass("main-bg");  
    if($(".contact").length === 0) {
        $("#main").append(
            "<div class=\"col-xs-12 contact\"><div id=\"contact-field\"><a href=\"mailto:xxxx@gmail.com\">xxxx@gmail.com</a><p>+xx xxx xx xx</p></div></div>"
        )
    };
});
```

after clicking the link it should remove html elements form the project-class, it should remove main-bg class from #main and then append some html to #main.

Pretty simple really, but can't figure out why it isn't working in Firefox.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: missing `event` perhaps? `.click(function(event) ...`

Comment: `event` is not a standard way to access the event object

Comment: I indeed had to pass my event, thanks @phillip100